# Smoothing a non-counter graph

Tags: prometheus, grafana, graphing

I am graphing the node_hwmon_temp_celsius metric from prometheus and would like to smooth out the graph a little as it's quite sensitive (1/3 of a degree) and shows a lot of spikes when the obvious trend would be more useful to see. The attached shows system temps in green and HDD temp (via smartmon) in yellow.

[image]

I have tried changing the Grafana resolution but that results in the same spikes, just "aliased". I've also tried the rate() function in Prometheus but the graph is nonsensical (with values range from 0-2) as I believe rate() needs a to work on a counter.

How can I smooth out these "absolute" values over time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure how I missed it, but the prometheus `avg_over_time` function does what I want.